# Is accessing different elements of an array in threads safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

In C++ if I have a `int x[2]` and I edit `x[0]` on one thread and `x[1]` on another thread at the same time is this safe? I presume that accessing the same element would be unsafe.

Comment: You presume correctly. You are safe unless there are other things afoot you haven't told us about.

Comment: As long as you don't modify the variable, reading only can be considered thread-safe.

Comment: @Asesh but I am reading and writing. Is that still safe?